# How to specify which client authentication certificate to use with wifi profile in Windows?

Tags: wireless-networking, certificate, authentication, profile

Using EAP-TLS authentication method allows users to authenticate on the Access Point using a client authentication certificate.

Via Windows wifi properties, you can choose "Smart Card or other Certificate Properties" tab in order to specify a certificate. However, you can choose certificate only by **Certificate Issuer** (please take a look at the screenshot below)

[image: Client certificate properties]

What may happen if you have multiple client authentication certificate, with the same Certificate Issuer? If that the case, how to specify which client authentication certificate will be used with wifi profile?

Comment: What happens if you uncheck "Use simple certificate selection"?

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this option enabled?

[image: this option enabled]